# Regex stop at the first double quote

Tags: regex, string

This is my string
    `'<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="<?=$modeValue?>"/>'`

I am trying to take 1) `name="mode"` and 2) `value="<?=$modeValue?>"`
from it.

I ran two regex to find it which is
    `/name\s*=\s*['\"].*['\"]/` for `name="mode"` and `/value\s*=\s*['\"].*['\"]/` for `value="<?=$modeValue?>"`

But I fail to get `name="mode"` on the first regex.
Instead I get `name="mode" value="$modeValue"`.

However I succeeded in getting `value="<?=$modeValue?>"`

What is wrong with my regex for `name="mode"`?
My observation, I think I have to make the regex stops at the first `"` it encounters. Anyone know how to do this. I am running out of time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little change and your regex is good to go.

```
name\s*=\s*['\"].*?['\"]
                  ^
```

Why your regex was not working the way you wanted.
So by nature **quantifiers** are **greedy** in nature so . will try to match as many characters as it can.

So by adding **?** we make it **lazy** which means it will now try to match as less character as it can.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SZFS1h/1)

In case you want to join both of regex together.

```
(name=\".*?\")\s*(value=\".*?\")|(value=\".*?\")\s*(name=\".*?\")
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/SZFS1h/3)

Comment: This is working the way I want. So the theory is, by making it lazy, it finds the .* and then it finds ['\"] and then, coz it being lazy, it wont go and search anymore? right?

Comment: @Salam.MSaif yeah.you can read here more about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions

Comment: @Salam.MSaif, this is rather complex for no reason. my answer is much more cleaner and straight forward, which is also what this answer has copied as the 2nd case.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori `(name=\".*?\")|(value=\".*?\")`  well in your case it will match `<input type="hidden" name="mode"/>` this too. i don't think op wants this. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create capturing groups to match both,

```
(name=\".*?\")\s*(value=\".*?\")
```

**Demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/z9dDE2/1

Comment: That is a nice way to do it. But considering that the string might be the other way around, say value="<?=$modeValue?>" name="mode", this might not work?

Comment: make it optional, `(name=\".*?\")|(value=\".*?\")`